# how to replace double in an array with index and value given by user and shifting each element to the right and dropping the last element

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0

I have a problem on replacing the value as I'm not sure which function to use or how to use it.

The question: Create and populate an array of 5 doubles. Ask the user to input a value ‘v’ and an index ‘i’. Your program should replace the value at index ‘i’ in the array with the value ‘v’ while shifting each element to the right and dropping the last element.

This is what I've done so far but it hasn't worked

```
double[] myDoubleArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

System.Console.Write(" Please input a value:  ");
int v = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

System.Console.Write(" Please input an index value:  ");
int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

myDoubleArray[i] = v;
```

Comment: You say "assignment", so I assume you're not allowed to use something like a `Queue<T>`?

Comment: You're right so far. You've replaced the value at `myDoubleArray[i]` with `v` as the assignment asks, but you need to manually shift the items to the right as/before you do. Right now, you've lost the original value at `myDoubleArray[i]` which is needed for `myDoubleArray[i + 1]` in the solution.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Array.Copy()`? That handles overlapping segments of the same array and would allow you to do this without writing your own loop. (I bet they want you to write a loop, though)

Comment: When you hand in your assignment, you should mention that arrays are the wrong collection type for this type of operation.  Arrays don't like being "shifted".

Comment: There are many different ways you could do this.. One would be to just convert it to a list and do an insert.  ```List<double> dbList = new List<double>(myDoubleArray); dbList.Insert(i,v);```. Though somehow I feel this is not the point of the assignment and that they want you to reconstruct the array with a for loop.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb no we arent allowed to use that yet

Comment: @DM sorry what do mean by ive lost the original value?

Comment: @PeterHenry yeah this unit is mainly on loops but I'm not sure exactly how to form a loop to move it all to the right

Comment: @Mostlygoldie I mean when you assign `myDoubleArray[i] = v`, you're overwriting the value that was there originally. You need to save this value first because it should be in `myDoubleArray[i +1]` when you finish the assignment. (Same for each other element to the right in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly saying that this is an assignment (which, in my mind, is OK, as long as you say so).  However, I don't like *doing* your assignments; if I do it, you won't learn anything.  Instead, I'm going to help you figure it out.  First your code:

```
double[] myDoubleArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

System.Console.Write(" Please input a value:  ");
int v = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

System.Console.Write(" Please input an index value:  ");
int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

myDoubleArray[i] = v;
```

Now the assignment, more explicitly:

- Create and populate an array of 5 doubles.
- Ask the user to input a value ‘v’ and an index ‘i’.
- Your program should replace the value at index ‘i’ in the array with the value ‘v’
- shifting each element to the right and dropping the last element.

You have done the first two parts.

What you need to do is do swap the last two pieces - first make room for the new element, and then, once there is a place for the new value, put it in.

To make room for the new value, you have two cases:

- The user picks the last index in the array.  In this case, you just overwrite the last element and your work is done
- The user picks any other index (0..N-2).  In that case, what you need to do is to loop over the array from the selected index to end of the array (less one), copying from the `i`th entry to the `i+1`th entry.  While you are doing this, you will likely find out why most programmers think that "off-by-one" issues are the most common bugs there are.

  - Think about this though.  You need to loop *backwards* (i.e. from the end of the array back towards the selected index).  If you do it in the normal *forwards* direction, then you will be overwriting things before you have created any space

Once you have "created some space", then overwrite the appropriate array entry.

Some other comments:

- You type your array as `double[]`, name it `myDoubleArray` and initialize it with `int`s.  All your interactions with your users use `int`s as well.  I realize that ints can be implicitly converted to doubles, but you should really decide what you want to do and do it consistently.  A double *literal* is just a number with a decimal point like `3.14152`
- You need to decide if you are going to number your indexes 0..N-1 (which C# likes) or 1..N (which humans like).  Write out a hint about this right at the top of your program.  Something like:

```
System.Console.WriteLine($"There is an an array with {myDoubleArray.Length} doubles in it, indexed 1 to {myDoubleArray.Length}.");
```

- The way you have your code, if a user enters an incorrectly formatted value, your program will throw an exception.  A user fat-fingering data entry is hardly *exceptional* behavior.  Consider using `int.TryParse` and `double.TryParse`.  They allow you to test for a good value before doing the conversion.  That way if the user enters bad data, you can repeat the prompt until he/she enters good data.

Enjoy